# memset fill file with 'a'

Tags: c, asynchronous, memset

Almost two hours I'm having problems with my program. I'm trying to fill my file with character 'a'but my program doesn't work. Here's my write function

```
int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
   int rv = 0;

   memset( (void *)aiorp, 'a', sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
   aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
   aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
   aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
   aiorp->aio_offset = 0;
   rv = aio_write( aiorp );

   if( rv == -1) {
       perror("ERROR!!!\n"); // my program print this (Invalid argument)
       exit(1);
       return rv;
   }
   return rv;
}
```

somehow rv fail `(rv == -1)` and I don't get expected results. Alsko I add my full program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <aio.h>

#define MB 1024

int da_open(const char *name);
int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count);
int da_test_wait( struct aiocb *aiorp );
int da_close(int fd);

int da_open(const char *name){
   int dskr;
   int dskr2;
   dskr = open( name, O_RDWR );
   if( dskr == -1 ){
       printf("Failas sukurtas, nes jo nebuvo\n");
       dskr2 = open( name, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0644);
   }else{
       printf("Toks failas jau yra!\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   printf( "dskr1 = %d\n", dskr2 );
   return dskr2;
}

int da_aio_write(const int d, struct aiocb *aiorp, void *buf, const int count){
   int rv = 0;

   memset( (void *)aiorp, 'a', sizeof( struct aiocb ) );
   aiorp->aio_fildes = d;
   aiorp->aio_buf = buf;
   aiorp->aio_nbytes = count;
   aiorp->aio_offset = 0;
   rv = aio_write( aiorp );

   if( rv == -1) {
       printf("ERROR!!! ");
       exit(1);
       return rv;
   }
   return rv;
}

int da_test_wait( struct aiocb *aiorp ){
   const struct aiocb *aioptr[1];
   int rv;
   aioptr[0] = aiorp;
   rv = aio_suspend( aioptr, 1, NULL );
   if( rv != 0 ){
      perror( "aio_suspend failed" );
      abort();
   }
   rv = aio_return( aiorp );
   printf( "AIO complete, %d bytes write.\n", rv );
   return 1;
}

int da_close(int fd){
   int rv;
   rv = close( fd );
   if( rv != 0 ) perror ( "close() failed" );
   else puts( "closed" );
   return rv;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[] ){
    int sk;
    int d;
    struct aiocb aior;
    if(argc == 3){
        sk = atoi(argv[2]);
        char buffer[MB * MB * sk];
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
        d = da_open(argv[1]);
        da_aio_write( d, &aior, buffer, sizeof(buffer) );
        da_test_wait( &aior );
        da_close( d );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check *why* [`aio_write`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/aio_write.3.html) fail? When it fails check [`errno`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html). Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to get a printable string from the error, or [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to print a message directly.

Comment: It looks like you are filling your struct with 'a' bytes and then immediately overwriting it by setting member variables of the struct

Comment: Thanks, I get Invalid argument.

Comment: @samgak I just set offset

Answer (score 1):

memset() has wrong parameters passing through. The line should be

```
memset(&aiorp, 'a', sizeof( struct aiocb ));
```

Here in the main() function you didn't assign anything to buffer.

the code inside da_aio_write() will be

```
memset(aiorp->aio_buf, 'a', count);
```

instead of: `memset((void *)aiorp,'a',sizeof(struct aiocb));`

there is no need of: `aiorp->aio_buf = buf;`

Comment: Thanks, but then I get Segmentation Fault(Core dumbed). And after testing with gdb I get this
0x08051026 in da_aio_write (d=3, aiorp=0x61616161, buf=0x61616161, count=1633771873) at ../src/internetas.c:39
39         aiorp->aio_fildes = d;

Comment: it is happening because aiorp is a pointer to the structure it is not the structure. Can you provide me the structure of aiorp.

Comment: aiorp is a POINTER to structure aiocb. I don't understand what's wrong there? :/

Comment: Here the problem with the memset(). It's making the runtime error. memset() is used usually for string. And the logic is not correct corresponding to your aim. You are first doing memeset the structure with 'a' but then you are assigning all the values. So why are you doing the memset()? Can you clear this purpose?

Comment: Well I want to fill buffer with 'a'. Should I use memset after I assigning all the values? (I try that but I get same reult...)

Comment: @David using memset you are setting the structure not the file. And what the whole logic is wrong to me. The program is not correct.
i) You have not assign anything inside buffer in main
ii) You are trying to fill structure with 'a'
iii) There is no string in structure...they are pointers
iv) The using of memset() is not applied here according to your logic.
Please think another logic for your goal, I can't help further on this code.